# Is there a way to apply typing.cast globally?

Tags: python, python-typing

```
class FooBar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.attr: Optional[str] = None
    
    def f(self):
        self.attr = 'a'
        print(self.attr.title())
```

If I tried to check the code above using MyPy, I would get an error: NoneType object does not have method title. Of course, I can use typing.cast locally, in f method, like so:

```
    def f(self):
        self.attr = 'a'
        cast(str, self.attr)
        print(self.attr.title())
```

But this would only cast type to the variable locally, that is in the f method. Is there a way to cast type globally so MyPy will not complain again?

Comment: If the attribute needs to be not-None "globally" should it even be Optional in the first place? Why not set it in `__init__` instead of this method?

Comment: It is a common practice to initialize all required attributes in constructor and only then change them.

Comment: In your example you should probably just do `self.attr = 'a'` in `__init__`, and be done with it. Then it doesn't need to be optional and is never `None`.

Comment: The problem is, in my situation attr is a coroutine, so I cannot init it in init method.

Comment: Why can you not init it  in `__init__`? Calling a coroutine does not schedule it to be executed.

Comment: You should probably give an example more representative of your actual scenario.

Comment: If you get `attr` from a coroutine, it's a good idea to just make it a `cached_property` instead. Various utility libraries provide an async version of it.